# Query runs on localhost perfectly but displays error when uploaded to server

Tags: php

I am using PDO in PHP for queries of database, when I run this query on localhost it works perfectly but when I upload this code to server it shows error

[image]

Comment: so can you show the code?

Comment: 'SELECT count(Gender) FROM `maro_tandoor`  where Gender="Male" and id IN (' . implode(',', array_map('intval', $usersArray)) . ') ';

Comment: I am using this query

Comment: (on browser this error is shown)Warning: array_map(): Argument #2 should be an array in /home/mtcom/public_html/marotandoors/classes/user.php on line 60

Warning: implode(): Invalid arguments passed in /home/mtcom/public_html/marotandoors/classes/user.php on line 60
Query failed with message: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ')' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

The Query was ok, I was passing different specific IDs from an other page through session, and session was not working properly. The issue was resolved then